# How can I tell a child process the pid of another child process in C?

Tags: c, parent-child

I am writing a program in which I need to create two child processes, a producer and a consumer. The producer writes on a file what is read from stdin, the consumer reads the same file after the producer has written the line. I need to synchronize the two processes and I wanted to do so by using signals, but I have now a problem in that I cannot send (using the kill() function) the signals from the consumer to the producer.

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catcherp(){};
void catcherc(){};

pid_t producer, consumer;

int main () {
int status_consumer, status_producer;
char string[128], reading[128];
FILE * fout, *finn;


producer = fork();
if (producer == 0){
    signal(SIGUSR2, catcherp);
    // producer process, child
    while(1){
        fout = fopen ("test.txt", "w");
        printf ("?: ");
        scanf ("%s", string);
        fputs(string, fout);        
        fclose(fout);

        kill(consumer, SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }

    exit(0);
}   else {
    // parent process
    consumer = fork ();
    if (consumer == 0) { 
        signal(SIGUSR1, catcherc);
        // consumer process, child
        while(1) {              
            pause();
            finn = fopen ("test.txt", "r");
            fgets(reading, 128, finn);
            printf("%s\n", reading);
            fclose(finn);               

            kill (producer, SIGUSR2);

        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("This is the parent process\n");
        waitpid(producer, &status_producer, 0);
        waitpid(consumer, &status_consumer, 0);
        printf("The children exited\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The exit(0) commands in both child processes are there because I still have to implement the exit condition for the loop. I am pretty sure that my problem lies in how I create the consumer process after creating the producer process. That means that the producer sees the "consumer" pid to be 0, which terminates the program.

Now, I would like to understand how I'm supposed to create two concurrent processes using the fork() function (if it's possible), can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You could arrange to pass the unknown PID on the pipe as the first message, as an example (which requires you to start the processes in the correct sequence: probably consumer first so producer already knows consumer PID, and can send the consumer its own PID).  However, you should ask yourself "why do you need signals to synchronize?" because signals are a heavy-weight, clumsy mechanism for doing anything.

Comment: synchronization between parent and child can be achieved using semaphore in your simple condition. in fact, the communication between two processes using a file is too heavy and error prone. a pipe for example, is a better approach.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I need signals because this is an exercise about signals for a programming course, so I  was trying to do it in that way even though it may seem silly. If you say that I should use the first message to get the pid, I guess my whole idea was wrong. I'll review it, thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: so you can use `getppid` to get pid of parent. http://linux.die.net/man/3/getppid

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could set the parent pid in a global via getpid() as well, and access that from the child.

Comment: about your telling one child about the pid of another question, in linux, there are two types of signals, standard and realtime. the realtime signals can carry `sigval` as parameter. check `man 7 signal`, `man sigqueue`. note that, though standard signals can still be registered using `sigaction`, but they can't receive parameter by construct. you will have to use realtime signals.

Comment: Fair enough: as an exercise in signalling, it makes some sense.  The difficulty of ensuring that both children know the other child's PID illustrates one of the problems of using signals.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to solve the problem, but I had to use the temporary file in order to get the pid of the producer process when inside the consumer process. 
I was hoping to find a smarter way but the solution given by the course was basically the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catcher(){};

int main () {
    int status_consumer, status_producer; // needed for the waitpid functions
    pid_t producer, consumer; // pids of the child processes
    char string[128]; // input string
    FILE * f; // fp

    signal (SIGUSR1, catcher);

    consumer = fork();
    if (consumer == 0) { 
        // child process
        while (1) {     
            pause(); // wait for the ready signal from the sender
            f = fopen ("tmp.txt", "r");
            fscanf (f, "%d %s", &producer, string); // read string and the pid of the sender
            printf("%s\n", string);   
            fclose(f); 

            if (strcmp("end", string) == 0) {
                break; // exit the loop when the word "end" is read
            }
            kill (producer, SIGUSR1);       
        }

        exit(0);
    } else {
        producer = fork (); 
        if (producer == 0) {
            // child process
            while(1) {      
                f = fopen ("tmp.txt", "w");
                printf("?: ");
                scanf("%s", string); // read from stdin the string
                fprintf(f, "%d\t%s\n", getpid(), string); // write on tmp.txt the string
                fclose(f);

                kill(consumer, SIGUSR1);
                if (strcmp("end", string) == 0){
                    break; // exit the loop when the word "end" is read
                }           
                pause();
            }
        } else {
            // parent process
            waitpid(producer, &status_producer, 0);
            waitpid(consumer, &status_consumer, 0);
        }

    }
     return 0;  // end of program
 }
```

Thanks for the comments

Comment: There are better ways to do IPC - for example, you could create a pipe and pass one fd to each child. Or, you could use a unix-domain socket.